# Virtual populated fields won't serialize in a type-graphql resolver

Tags: mongoose, graphql, typegraphql, typegoose

Stack - Type-graphql with Typegoose

Problem :

1. BookRecommendation class resolves a book (virtual field)
2. Typegoose returns the correct populated value for book which is resolved through bookId foreign ref
3. The serialized type-graphql response doesn't include book object and have tried all ways to figure that out.

What is the correct way to serialize the book object?

```
@ObjectType()
export class BookRecommendation {
  @Field()
  readonly _id!: ObjectId;

  @prop() @Field(() => Date)
  createdAt!: Date;

  @prop() @Field(() => Date)
  updatedAt!: Date;

  @prop() @Field()
  sourceUrl!: string;

  @prop() @Field()
  recommendation!: string;

  @prop({ref: Book, }) @Field(type => ObjectIdScalar)
  bookId!: Ref<Book>;

  @prop({ref: Influencer}) @Field(type => ObjectIdScalar)
  influencerId!: Ref<Influencer>;

  @prop({
    ref: 'Book',
    foreignField: '_id', // compare this value to the local document populate is called on
    localField: 'bookId', // compare this to the foreign document's value defined in "foreignField",
    justOne: true,
  }) 
  public book: Book;
}

export const MongooseBookReco = getModelForClass(BookRecommendation, {schemaOptions : {timestamps: true, toObject : { depopulate: false, versionKey: true,  virtuals: true, getters: true } }});

// Service Class
@Service() // Dependencies injection
export default class BookRecommendationService {
  constructor(private readonly bookRecoModel: BookRecommendationModel) {}

  public async getById(_id: ObjectId): Promise<BookRecommendation | null> {
    return MongooseBookReco.findById(_id).populate('book').exec();
  }

  public async find(): Promise<BookRecommendation[]> {
    return MongooseBookReco.find().populate('book').exec();
  }
  
  public async addBookRecommendation(data: NewBookRecommendationInput): Promise<BookRecommendation> {
    const newBookRecommendation = await this.bookRecoModel.create(data);
    return newBookRecommendation;
  }
}


// Resolver class trying to resolve the 
 @Query((returns) => BookRecommendation, {name: "BookRecommendation"})
  async BookRecommendation(@Arg("id") id: ObjectId) {
    const reco = await this.recoService.getById(id);
    console.log(reco);
    return reco;
  }

// Console.log output of reco object above. It contains book
{
  _id: 601e3a416f05d67955cf5477,
  sourceUrl: 'https://twitter.com/joerogan/status/276827723358404608?s=20',
  recommendation: 'Mind blowing book',
  bookId: 601e2ebbdda47174163d718d,
  influencerId: 601a362796e4c3a3650bcaf6,
  __v: 0,
  book: {
    _id: 601e2ebbdda47174163d718d,
    title: 'Sex at dawn',
    amazonUrl: 'https://www.amazon.com/dp/0061707813?tag=mostrecommendedbooks-20&geniuslink=true',
    __v: 0
  },
  id: '601e3a416f05d67955cf5477'
}


// Client graphl query the trigger above code
query {
  BookRecommendation(id: "601e3a416f05d67955cf5477") {
    recommendation
    _id
    bookId
    influencerId
    
  }
}


// Graph QL serialized output at client misses book object

{
  "data": {
    "BookRecommendation": {
      "recommendation": "Mind blowing book",
      "_id": "601e3a416f05d67955cf5477",
      "bookId": "601e2ebbdda47174163d718d",
      "influencerId": "601a362796e4c3a3650bcaf6"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: did you already try converting your type to an POJO before giving it to graphql? mongoose is known to not include virtuals in and `.toObject` / `.toJSON` call, you can active this with `@modelOptions({ schemaOptions: { toJSON: { virtuals: true }, toObject: { virtuals: true } } })` or `doc.toJSON({ virtuals: true })`

Comment: Hey thanks. it is still a graphql response that is missing the virtual field. Yes tried `@modelOptions({ schemaOptions: { toJSON: { virtuals: true }, toObject: { virtuals: true } } })` on the class and on the field as well `export const MongooseBookReco = getModelForClass(BookRecommendation, {schemaOptions : {timestamps: true, toObject : { depopulate: false, versionKey: true,  virtuals: true, getters: true } }});
`